# How to make use named stored procedure for below query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, stored-procedures, jpa-2.0

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GL REPORT_SP`(IN con CHAR(50),IN dt CHAR(50),IN ddt CHAR(50))
BEGIN
select a.gl, 
#cast((amp_tot /100) as decimal(9,2)) amp_tot, 
amp_tot, 
rds_tot,
(amp_tot * -1) + rds_tot as difference,

cast(((rds_tot + (amp_tot * -1)) / rds_tot) * 100 as decimal(9,2)) as variance
#(cast(rds_tot as decimal(9,2)) + cast((amp_tot /100) as decimal(9,2))) as difference
from 
(
                select 
                gl, cast(sum(totamt) as decimal(9,2)) as AMP_TOT
                from avsamp a
                where convert(ddate, date) = dt
                #and wizco in ('082', '085')
    and cocountry in (con)
                group by gl
                #order by wizco, cocountry, gl;

                #select distinct(wizco), gl, sum(totamt) amp_tot
                #, WIZco, sum(TOTAMT )
                #from budamp
                #where ddate = '20181101'
                #group by gl
                #order by gl

) a
left join 
(
                select 
                a.rdsgl, cast(sum(totamt) as decimal(9,2)) as RDS_TOT
                from avsrds a
                where uncntry = con
                and ddate = ddt
                group by a.rdsgl
                #order by a.rdsgl
) b on b.rdsgl = a.gl
order by a.gl;
END
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Table(name = "PAYRDS")
@Primary
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({ @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "firstProcedure", procedureName = "getCountDetails"),
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery( name = "secondProcedure", procedureName = "getRDSByCountry", parameters = {
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN , name = "Country", type = String.class)}), 
            @NamedStoredProcedureQuery( name = "thirdProcedure", procedureName = "getResultByDateCountry",
                    resultClasses = { RDS8887.class },
                    parameters = {
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(
                            mode = ParameterMode.IN , name = "Country", type = String.class), 
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(
                            mode = ParameterMode.IN , name = "ddate", type = String.class),
                    })
})
```

For the GL Report, I need to make use of two table to make use of named stored procedure that will be mapped with 2 classes. I wrote a stored procedure that makes use of one class which is `RDS8887`, but I am having hard time with how to use 2 classes?

Comment: I solved the issue with creating a class with those specific fields, but is there any other ways to do it